# Could a moderator please remove this discussion

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/7723/how-much-did-pauls-travels-cost/7760#comment21545_7760) has a long discussion that has the potential to be medically dangerous. Please could a moderator remove the entire discussion, including contributions from me.

Answer (score 4):

I have removed all comments as unconstructive. Also, in the future, you can flag for the same effect; only mods can see and act on comment flags.

Comment: also they are annonymous

Comment: Thanks. I'll use flag in the future.

Comment: @DJClayworth: Not only will flags serve the purpose of alerting a moderator to the need for such cleanup, sometimes a moderator won't even have to step in. All it takes is a couple user flags on a given comment and they will automatically be removed.

Comment: just a passing nod of appreciation - that discussion was... scary.